# Abstract Algebra Groups of Order 2p

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Groups of order 2p, where p is an odd prime. Suppose that G an element of order 2p. Prove that G isomorphic to Z2p. Hence G is cyclic. I can not use Sylow's theorem though since it has not yet been taught.

Comment: Is the question really asking whether if $G$ has order $2p$ and $G$ has an element $g$ of order $2p$ then $G$ is cyclic?

Comment: It is asking if the group G is isomorphic to ℤ2p.

Comment: Why would you want to use Sylow's Theorem anyway?

Comment: I found this solution several times and every single answer used Sylow's Theorem and it has not been taught in class yet.

Answer (score 2):

If $G$ is a finite group of order $n$  (not necessarily of the form $2p$)  and $g$ is an element of order $n$ in $G$, then $G=<g>$. So $G$ is cyclic and isomorph to $Z_n$!

Comment: True, but I need to show that G is isomorphic to ℤ2p to show that it is Cyclic.

Comment: By the definition the group that generated by one element is cyclic, isn't it?